# One to many SQL relationship

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

- I am trying to build one-to-many relationship between Project table and Report table.
- User can create new project, later he can create one or more new reports related to that project.
- These two tables will be used for reporting issues. For example, if I build a new app, I will create a new project that hold my app's name. Then later when I test my app on certain device like PC or iPhone and I faced an issue, I will create a new report about the issue.

---

```
class Project(db.Model):
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.Date)

    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Report(db.Model):
    report_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.project_id'))
    project = db.relationship('Report', backref='reports', lazy='dynamic')
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    issue = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, project_id, date, issue):
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.date = date
        self.issue = issue

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.issue
```

Questions:

1. Is the connection between the two tables correct as a one to many relationship?
2. Is the **init** function really required here? I saw some code online without them!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flask-SQLAlchemy's documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/models/#one-to-many-relationships) covers creating a one-to-many relationship. It provides an example of one `Person` having many `Address`es.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person',
                                lazy='dynamic')

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

This matches what you have. The only difference is that the example places the relationship on the parent model. It can be placed on either model. I try to always place it on the one where it makes the most sense.

As for your `__init__` methods, they are most likely unnecessary. Flask-SQLAlchemy's `Model` class has an `__init__` that accepts keyword arguments that allow you to assign values to columns. The difference is that your versions require the specified fields whereas the default version doesn't require any.

Your version only works as

```
project = Project('My Project', date(2015, 4, 23))
```

`Model`'s version not only works the same way, but it also works as

```
project = Project()
project.name = 'My Project'
project.date = date(2015, 4, 23)
```

Comment: You are Awesome @dirn.

>  The only difference is that the example places the relationship on the parent model. It can be placed on either model.

This really explains it! I saw this person-address example when I was searching but then I saw other one to many relationship examples, and they differ in the relationship line, that's what make me confuse.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The **init** function is there so you that when you create an instance of a class, you can set starting values or perform initialization functions. If you feel you do not need to do such things, you can omit the **init** definition.

Comment: > If you feel you do not need to do such things, you can omit the init definition.

Thank you Rohn, that helped